# .htm pages working but .aspx pages throwing errors

Tags: iis, asp.net

Our site has thousands of visitors per day but we've been receiving reports from some of our members that they are able to hit our main page, presumably because it's a .htm page, but when they click off to a .aspx page, they get an error.

I've done as much research as I know how and here is what I have come up with:

- We have not made any changes to IIS on our server in months.
- We have a couple of customers that have been willing to work with us and provide information about their system. One customer is running Vista, the other is running XP.
- We had one of the customers test both Firefox and MSIE. She gets same error in both.
- One customer said:

> We were able to post the profile and
>   searched on available jobs and it
>   worked w/ Firefox for a day, then it
>   just quit working...we did not change
>   any settings to Firefox after we
>   posted the profile.

- We asked the customer to clear their cache and try again. They responded with, "We just cleared the cache and got the same error; btw, I periodically clear the cache -- almost every day."

Summary
We have thousands of customers that hit our site with no problem. We can't reproduce these errors. These customers are getting the same error in different browsers. They are only getting the error on .aspx pages. They still get the error after clearing their cache.

We would appreciate any thoughts on what other questions we could ask these customers or thoughts on how we can further troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Please say which error they get. "An error" isn't helpful at all.

Comment: `We were able to post the profile and searched on available jobs and it worked w/ Firefox for a day, then it just quit working`. I would probably ask them to clarify the `quit working` part. Also you should have extensive logging in your application to analyze this kind of situations and not rely on customers to tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the specific error would help a lot in troubleshooting this...

We've ran into a few similar issues in the past that might be worth looking into: 
* Corporate proxies (especially if they're using some sort of content scanning proxy) 
* AV / Firewall software on the desktop (they'll sometimes mangle scripts or mess with browsers)
* Connection type & provider (we've actually seen issues with a small subset of our customers on a specific type of PPPoE connection due to weird MTU sizes - weird but rare)

For additional troubleshooting, try to get the customer's IP address and grep through your server logs for any additional messages pertaining to their browser session.